# Order of importance for each level of a feature in Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

After fitting a model using SciKitLearn's Random Forest Classifier I get the feature importance list, but can I get the importance of level of a feature.

For example, if I get the series below for feature importance, how can I see which day_of_week is most important?

```
online_users            0.107735
number_of_post          0.051478
day_of_week             0.042552
total_votes             0.131286
polarity                0.033352
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can create a dummy variable for the day_of_week and then run the feature importance on the new feature set after merging the dummies and dropping day_of_week.

```
pd.get_dummies(df['day_of_week'])
```

Comment: This works! But oddly it also significantly improves the prediction accuracy of my model but that should not be the case, right?

Comment: It's not odd actually, this is feature engineering that makes the model more robust to learn the data in a better way.